# IF Statement if it match range of data

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

Dear all experts here,

How should I draft my IF Statement here if I am looking to label "Yes" and "No" if it match the date in Column B. **[Here is the trix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=1120515726)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((A2:A29>=B2)*(A2:A29<B3), "Yes", "No"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, if you can help to take a look at the sheet again, I made a slight mistake of what I want. I want to be if it matches the date in column B. I have altered the trix bit, hope you can help me solve it. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=1120515726

Comment: @2dayholiday sure. see your sheet https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejI5H.png